# How would I use Math objects to scale by the length of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think its `Math.floor(Math.random() * .length)` I am confused on what I should put before `.length`

```
var example0 = new array("example", "example2");
```

Would I put  `Math.floor(Math.random() * example0.length` ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Open your developer console so you can see the error you're given.

Answer (score 0):

```
var example0 = new Array("example", "example2");

alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * example0.length));
```

Before ask, try to do it on your own, check your developer console to catch errors, logs. There is a lot of information (in your developer console). All we are humans and time to time get bored, tired and as a result we all make mistakes or just misspelling.